# Transformer in 127V AC - 5V DC Converter

Tags: transformer, circuit-design, ac-dc, conversion

There is a transformer in this 127V AC to 5V DC Converter. I am trying to get one of them. But I don't know what kind of transformer is and I am unable to find it in my city. 
[image]

Also, it is so small. When I ask in the local electronics shops about a transformer capable of converting 127 V to 5 V. They give me a very big transformer. So I don't know how it is possible that this little transformer do the same. The circuit specifications are these:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: That's the only component I am unable to find. And I think it is very interesting that you can use transformers that small for applications like these. So I want to know exactly what it is. Because if I know what it is, then I would be able to use smaller transformers and make PCBs that I designed smaller and lighter

Comment: I am not going to buy it yet. For the moment, I just want to know how that circuit works. And what component is that.

Comment: Maybe I need to change the question for: How this converter works?

Comment: This is isolated [flyback converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_converter).

Comment: Is not a buck converter?

Comment: [Buck converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter) is non-isolated circuit which is inappropriate for mains power supplies.

Comment: So, WhatRoughBeast is wrong?, it is not a buck converter?

Answer (score 1):

Check the two black electrolytic caps on the left in your first picture. Are they rated for about 400 - 450 volts?

If so, what you have is an input rectifier which will produce a high DC voltage at the caps. The transformer is then part of a switch-mode power supply which is effectively a DC-DC converter which converts high voltage to low. Also known as a buck converter.

Something you'll need to learn about transformers is that the higher the operating frequency the smaller the transformer needs to be for a given power level. So, as Michael Karas answered, the transformer will operate at about 200 kHz rather than 50-60 Hz,and can be much smaller than a transformer which operates at line frequency.

And why 200 kHz, you ask? It's part of a compromise. While increasing the switching frequency reduces the size of the magnetics, it also increases the power dissipated in the switching device, usually a MOSFET. So, depending on the exact circuit and construction, switching power supplies usually run at about 100 kHz (more or less), where the value of the continued shrinkage will be outweighed by the increased power dissipation of the switch. The exact frequency will depend on exactly what circuit is used, what components are selected, what voltage/current combination is specified, the temperature limits on the circuit, emitted RFI issues, and a bunch of other considerations.

Comment: Yes, they are labeled as: 400V 10uF. So, the capacitors rectify the signal?

Comment: Probably it is important to mention that there are more components on the back of the PCB. There is one called ABS10 .. It is very small too, But I think that is the one that rectifies the signal

Comment: @Delfin The capacitors don't rectify it, the diodes do. The capacitors just give you a hint at what's going on, because if it wasn't some kind of switching converter you wouldn't need those capacitors.

Comment: @Delfin - No, the caps store energy after the input has been rectified by something else. I can't see enough of the board to identify the rectifier.

Comment: The rectifier is at the back of the PBC. I didn't take photo of that

Comment: @Delfin - "The rectifier is at the back of the PBC." Maybe it is, maybe it isn't. I'm not sure you know what to look for. And since you did not realize that capacitors are not rectifiers, I'm not going to take your word for it. And neither should you.

Comment: I realized that the capacitors are not the rectifiers. I know it is at the back because I have the datasheet  of the ABS10 component, and it says: "Glass Pasivated Bridge Rectifiers". It was weird for me that the capacitors were the ones that rectify the signal, that's why I asked you. But I think now everything makes sense. More or less ...

Comment: @Delfin - Ah. Well then, sorry I doubted you. Carry on.

Comment: But then, it is not a buck converter, it is a flyback converter; and the transformer is the one that appears in flyback converter diagrams: https://www.nuffzedd.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/flyback.jpg

Comment: @Delfin - Sorry, but any DC-DC converter with a lower output than input is a buck converter, and any DC-DC converter with a higher output than input is a boost converter. Which circuit topology is used to achieve this is an entirely separate matter.

Comment: Are you sure? Because they are actually in different sections. Buck, Boost, Buck-Boost Converters are not isolated, and Flyback Converter is Isolated. I guess you can say Buck–boost converter is the analog of Flyback Converter. If it was a Buck converter, it wouldn't even have sense talking about the transformer because Buck, Boost and Buck-Boost converters doesn't require a one, at least from what I see of the squematics

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for a transformer you should be searching for a PCB mount switching power supply module.

5V at 2A is a ten watt unit and can be found. If you are looking for repair replacement then your challenge will be to find one with same form and fit.

Comment: But what kind of transformer is it?. Normal transformers are not that small. I am just looking to understand how these little converters work

Comment: Your first photo is a DC-DC converter, or switch-mode power supply.  As marked on the transformer, the supply operates at 200 KHz - a transformer operating at that frequency requires much less iron (or a much smaller core) that one operating at 50 or 60 Hz.  You are very unlikely to find a replacement transformer, as that one was almost certainly custom designed for that power supply.

Comment: Is not a DC-DC Converter. It is an AC-DC Converter. The second photo shows the case where the circuit was inside. And it says: Input: 100-240V ~ 50-60 Hz, Output: 5V 2A max. In Mexico, we use 127 V AC at 60 Hz